Loop Cut is not working the way I want it to
When I was making a toilet for some reason after I dissolved some faces on the side it wont let me loop cut on certain faces and I can only loop cut on the sides.

Your top face is not a quad, it's a ngon, loopcuts can't cut ngons because Blender doesn't know where it is supposed to cut, so you either need to create a quad (image) or use a knife to create your edge loop (K to enable, A to cut orthogonally, C to cut through):

